# How to show the webform submission page as pop up?

Tags: 8, webforms, javascript

I have created the webform with two fields. When I submit the webform, its redirecting to the submission page.

Now, I want to display the webform submission page as pop up.

Thank you message and the "Back to form" should display in the pop up.

I have tried up with the NG lightbox to display the message. But its redirecting to the page with the pop up function.

How to achieve this thing, Please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

It is very difficult (but not impossible) to target a lightbox/modal when submitting a form because the posted database has to be sent to the server.

I recommend following the below ticket on Drupal.org which could help you solve your problem using Ajax.

[Allow Webforms to be submitted using AJAX](https://www.drupal.org/node/2757491)